# Replace a regular expression with another regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace some regex with regex in java for e.g.

**Requirement:**

Input: xyxyxyP

Required Output : xyzxyzxyzP

**means I want to replace "(for)+\{" to "(for\{)+\{"** . Is there any way to do this?

I have tried the following code

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class ReplaceDemo2 {

    private static String REGEX = "(xy)+P";
    private static String INPUT = "xyxyxyP";
    private static String REGEXREPLACE = "(xyz)+P";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        // get a matcher object
        Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
        INPUT = m.replaceAll(REGEXREPLACE);
        System.out.println(INPUT);
    }
}
```

but the output is  *(xyz)+P* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with a `\G` based regex:

```
String s = "xyxyxyP";
String pattern = "(?:(?=xy)|(?!^)\\G)xy(?=(?:xy)*P)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pattern, "$0z"));
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP5zN0/2) and [an IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uAISiL).

In short, the regex matches:

- `(?:(?=xy)|(?!^)\\G)` - either a location followed with `xy` (`(?=xy)`) or the location after the previous successful match (`(?!^)\\G`)
- `xy` - a sequence of literal characters `xy` but only if followed with...
- `(?=(?:xy)*P)` - zero or more sequences of `xy` (due to `(?:xy)*`) followed with a `P`.

Comment: Can you please share regx of getting "xyzabzxyzP" from "xyabxyP"?

Comment: No idea what the pattern can be. Try `.replaceAll("xy|(?!P)[^x]*(?:x(?!y)[^x]*)*(?=.*P)", "$0z")`.